# Retrieving and Reading Data as NSArray from Firebase (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I'm working through a course on Udemy to build a chat app with Firebase, Backendless, and Swift. All of the issues (it was written for Swift 2 not 3) I've been able to resolve myself, but this one has me stumped. This function is supposed to retrieve data from the Firebase database, and apparently it was supposed to retrieve it as an NSArray, but it now retrieves it as an NSDictionary, which is making a huge list of errors in the other functions because it's not expecting a dictionary.

```
func loadRecents() {
 firebase.childByAppendingPath("Recent").queryOrderedByChild("userId").queryEqualToValue(currentUser.objectId).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
      snapshot in
      self.recents.removeAll()
      if snapshot.exists() {
            let sorted = (snapshot.value.allValues as NSArray).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([NSSortDescriptior(key: "date", ascending: false)])
      }
   })
}
```

I've updated to Swift 3 as far as:

```
func loadRecents() {
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let userId = currentUser?.getProperty("username") as! String
    ref.child("Recent").queryOrdered(byChild: "userId").queryEqual(toValue: userId).observe(.value, with: {
        snapshot in
        self.recents.removeAll()
        if snapshot.exists() {
            let values = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
        }
    })
}
```

Of course, using `as! NSArray` does not work. Would very much appreciate it if anyone can suggest a method to update this to use Swift 3, sort it by a value in the data, and be able to access it later on. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func loadRecents() {
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let userId = currentUser?.getProperty("username") as! String
ref.child("Recent").queryOrdered(byChild: "userId").queryEqual(toValue: userId).observe(.value, with: {
    snapshot in
    self.recents.removeAll()
    if snapshot.exists() {
        let values = snapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]
    }
})}
```

or you can use also `let values = snapshot.value as! [Any]`

Comment: Thank you, this helped, but I see from doing more research that I should be using `for child in snapshot.children {
  let myvalue = child.value["my value"] as! String
}` or something of the like to comb through the child nodes. However, when I do this it says "NSFastEnumerationIterator has no element value", then it suggests I cast it to AnyObject, but of course this does not work either. Do you know how to make this work?

Comment: @EthanT first you must check "child" return type do with debug mode

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you, try this code:

```
func loadRecents() {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let userId = currentUser?.getProperty("username") as! String
    ref.child("Recent").queryOrdered(byChild: "userId").queryEqual(toValue: userId).observe(.value, with: {
        snapshot in
        self.recents.removeAll()
        guard let mySnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] else { return }
        for snap in mySnapshot {
            if let userDictionary = snap.value as? [String: Any] {
                print("This is userKey \(snap.key)")
                print("This is userDictionary \(userDictionary)")
            }
        }
    })
}
```